# Getting a record set that has two or more different users

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find all calls in a given range that have been handled by more than one customer care agent. Using a "HAVING COUNT" gets me half way there but I also get results that have the same person in multiple legs of the same call. I need to filter out only those with to different names. Here my query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM call_legs
WHERE call_id IN (
SELECT DISTINCT(call_id)
FROM call_legs
    WHERE call_id IN (
        SELECT 
        call_id
        FROM call_legs
        WHERE 
            from_name IN (SELECT name FROM directory WHERE include = 'Yes' AND discription = 'Customer Care')
            AND call_legs.start_time >= '10/09/2022 12:00 AM' AND call_legs.start_time <= '10/16/2022 11:59 PM' 
            AND result = 'Call connected'
            GROUP BY call_id
            HAVING COUNT (from_name) > 1
    )
)
AND from_name IN (SELECT name FROM directory WHERE include = 'Yes' AND discription = 'Customer Care')
AND result = 'Call connected'
ORDER BY start_time ASC
```

Comment: do a join and test the users for unequally

Comment: yea, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`. It's also totally unnecessary inside a sub-query used for an IN condition.

Comment: @James Have you tried `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT from_name) > 1`?